# Angular JS 2 : Capture the some specified requests if network fails and again send them

Tags: angularjs

My requirements are like below :
I have Actions URLs say 
["http://yyy.com/abrakadabra1", "http://yyy.com/abrakadabra2"]

and maxActionsToSave : 3, waitingDuration : 30(sec)

I have to save requests if it matches to Action Urls Array upto maxActionsToSave times or wait upto waitingDuration constants if in case no network(As network is very very slow having fluctuation also).

If any requests(May be time sync action or any other requests) got success then push these saved actions else throw exception if none of requests has got success or try up to some number of specified actions. After waiting limit or action limit gone http request can through exceptions.

Comment: Is this AngularJS or Angular 2+?  There is no AngularJS 2.

Comment: Either way, I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.  Can you clarify what your problem is?  Maybe with a little more of the code in question.

Comment: It is Angular JS 2 only.

Comment: I am making one Demo of Online Test project where three action happening:
1. Submit Answer (on clicking of submit button or radio button)
2. Show next / previous question (on clicking of next/previous button)
3. TimeSynch (this is getting called to make the same time between server and client)

Suppose on test duration network fluctuates so i am getting error and throwing exception for every request. I want to save some answer/question data then freeze the screen not for TimeSync. And retry same request depending on numberOfRetry or waitingTime limit. Else can throw exception.